# Concurrency in CUDA multi-GPU executions

Tags: concurrency, cuda, gpu, multiple-gpu

I'm running a cuda kernel function on a multiple GPUs system, with `4` GPUs. I've expected them to be launched concurrently, but they are not. I measure the starting time of each kernel, and the second kernel starts after the first one finishes its execution. So launching the kernel on `4` GPUs is not faster than `1` single GPU.

How can I make them work concurrently?

This is my code:

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
GPU_kernel<<< gridDim, threadsPerBlock >>>(d_result_0, parameterA +(0*rateA), parameterB + (0*rateB));
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_result_0, d_result_0, mem_size_result, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaSetDevice(1);
GPU_kernel<<< gridDim, threadsPerBlock >>>(d_result_1, parameterA +(1*rateA), parameterB + (1*rateB));
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_result_1, d_result_1, mem_size_result, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaSetDevice(2);
GPU_kernel<<< gridDim, threadsPerBlock >>>(d_result_2, parameterA +(2*rateA), parameterB + (2*rateB));
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_result_2, d_result_2, mem_size_result, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaSetDevice(3);
GPU_kernel<<< gridDim, threadsPerBlock >>>(d_result_3, parameterA +(3*rateA), parameterB + (3*rateB));
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_result_3, d_result_3, mem_size_result, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: The changes you have made will make no difference, you have to use a stream with `cudaMemcpyAsync` otherwise the behaviour is identical to `cudaMemcpy`. To make that code work, do *all* the kernel launches first, then do all the copies afterwards. The copies will still block one another, but all the kernels will run in parallel.

Comment: @talonmies but copying is the most time consuming part (it takes 1000 times more that kernel launch!) is there any mechanism to make them run in parallel?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the timing. Because the kernel launch is asynchronous, and the copying blocking, the copy time you are measuring includes both kernel execution and copying. You can confirm this by inserting a cudaDeviceSynchronize between kernel launch and copy. Watch as the memcpy gets faster and the cudaDeviceSynchronize takes up most of the time. Then go back and re-read my comment and @aland's answer, they contain two valid solutions to you problem.

Comment: @talonmies, cudaMemcpyAsync() behavior on the NULL stream is *not* identical to cudaMemcpy().  cudaMemcpy() is fully synchronous.  cudaMemcpyAsync() will return control to the caller before the operation is completed.

Comment: @user1555209: what platform is this on?  If Windows, and WDDM is enabled (the default since Windows Vista), the cudaSetDevice() calls are "thunking" into kernel mode to submit work to the hardware.  That is a sufficiently expensive operation that it may be overwhelming the hardware's ability to execute these kernels in parallel.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware I'm using Linux platform

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have done some experiments on achieving concurrent execution on a cluster of `4` Kepler K20c GPUs. I have considered `8` test cases, whose corresponding codes along with the profiler timelines are reported below.

**Test case #1 - "Breadth-first" approach - synchronous copy**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T *d_data;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

    double *inputMatrices = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    // --- "Breadth-first" approach - no async
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(plan[k].d_data, inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*
[image]

As it can be seen, the use of `cudaMemcpy` does not enable achieving concurrency in copies, but concurrency is achieved in kernel execution.

**Test case #2 - "Depth-first" approach - synchronous copy**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T *d_data;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

    double *inputMatrices = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    // --- "Depth-first" approach - no async
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(plan[k].d_data, inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*

[image]

This time, concurrency is not achieved neither within memory copies nor within kernel executions.

**Test case #3 - "Depth-first" approach - asynchronous copy with streams**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T               *d_data;
    T               *h_data;
    cudaStream_t    stream;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost((void **)&plan.h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaStreamCreate(&plan.stream));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

     // --- "Depth-first" approach - async
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++)
    {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].d_data, plan[k].h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, plan[k].stream));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE, 0, plan[k].stream>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].h_data, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, plan[k].stream));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*

[image]

Concurrency is achieved, as expected.

**Test case #4 - "Depth-first" approach - asynchronous copy within default streams**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T               *d_data;
    T               *h_data;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost((void **)&plan.h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

    // --- "Depth-first" approach - no stream
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++)
    {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].d_data, plan[k].h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].h_data, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*

[image]

Despite using the default stream, concurrency is achieved.

**Test case #5 - "Depth-first" approach - asynchronous copy within default stream and unique host `cudaMallocHost`ed vector**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T               *d_data;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

    // --- "Depth-first" approach - no stream
    double *inputMatrices;   gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost(&inputMatrices, N * sizeof(double)));
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++)
    {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].d_data, inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*

[image]

Concurrency is achieved once again.

**Test case #6 - "Breadth-first" approach with asynchronous copy with streams**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
// --- Async
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T               *d_data;
    T               *h_data;
    cudaStream_t    stream;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost((void **)&plan.h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaStreamCreate(&plan.stream));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

    // --- "Breadth-first" approach - async
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].d_data, plan[k].h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, plan[k].stream));
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE, 0, plan[k].stream>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].h_data, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, plan[k].stream));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*

[image]

Concurrency achieved, as in the corresponding "depth-first" approach.

**Test case #7 - "Breadth-first" approach - asynchronous copy within default streams**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
// --- Async
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T               *d_data;
    T               *h_data;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost((void **)&plan.h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

    // --- "Breadth-first" approach - async
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].d_data, plan[k].h_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].h_data, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*

[image]

Concurrency is achieved, as in the corresponding "depth-first" approach.

**Test case #8 - "Breadth-first" approach - asynchronous copy within the default stream and unique host `cudaMallocHost`ed vector**

*- Code -*

```
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE 128

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<class T>
__global__ void kernelFunction(T * __restrict__ d_data, const unsigned int NperGPU) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < NperGPU) for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) d_data[tid] = d_data[tid] * d_data[tid];

}

/******************/
/* PLAN STRUCTURE */
/******************/
// --- Async
template<class T>
struct plan {
    T               *d_data;
};

/*********************/
/* SVD PLAN CREATION */
/*********************/
template<class T>
void createPlan(plan<T>& plan, unsigned int NperGPU, unsigned int gpuID) {

    // --- Device allocation
    gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(gpuID));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&(plan.d_data), NperGPU * sizeof(T)));
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int numGPUs   = 4;
    const int NperGPU   = 500000;
    const int N         = NperGPU * numGPUs;

    plan<double> plan[numGPUs];
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) createPlan(plan[k], NperGPU, k);

    // --- "Breadth-first" approach - async
    double *inputMatrices;   gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost(&inputMatrices, N * sizeof(double)));
    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(plan[k].d_data, inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        kernelFunction<<<iDivUp(NperGPU, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(plan[k].d_data, NperGPU);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numGPUs; k++) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(k));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(inputMatrices + k * NperGPU, plan[k].d_data, NperGPU * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

*- Profiler timeline -*

[image]

Concurrency is achieved, as in the corresponding "depth-first" approach.

**Conclusion**
*Using asynchronous copies guarantees concurrent executions, either using purposely created streams or using the default stream.*

**Note**
*In all the above examples, I have taken care to provide enough work to do the GPUs, either in terms of copies and of computing tasks. Failing to provide enough work to the cluster may prevent observing concurrent executions.*

Comment: This answer is absolutely excellent. I keep coming back here using this for reference. You might consider publishing this somewhere else too considering the low number of views on this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to use `cudaMemcpyAsync`. `cudaMemcpy` is blocking call, so it does not return execution to your code before it finishes, so your code just does not switch GPU before it completes the routine for the current one.

<strike>However, kernel calls are asynchronous (for CPU), so the code you posted is likely to cause some race-conditions (`cudaMemcpy` *might* start executing before kernel finishes).</strike>
As @talonmies pointed out in the comments, since `cudaMemcpy`/`cudaMemcpyAsync` goes into the same stream as kernel launch, everything is executed in right order.

I would recommend you to use CUDA Streams; [here](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-multi-gpu.pdf) is a brief introduction to MultiGPU programming using streams. It's not very helpful in your case, but might be very convenient to use in more complex applications, e.g. if you need to synchronize function calls between different devices.

Comment: I don't follow your second paragraph. When would a `cudaMemcpy` call into the default stream overlap with kernel execution in the default stream?

Comment: dear aland

thanks for your answer. but as described on the page 6 of the link which you've sent, all GPUs should be executing concurrently (without use of streaming and event) I'm executing a code very similar to the example, but they don't work concurrently. and I just tested the cudaMemcpyAsync, but the timing didn't change