# CUDA multi - gpu add function

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu

I followed the following example:
[multi-GPU basic usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529972/multi-gpu-basic-usage)

The Code is doing summation:

The man who is answered checked as accepted, sends add function like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) {
    for(int dev=0; dev<2; dev++) {
        cudaSetDevice(dev);
        add<<<NB,NT>>>( dev_a[dev], dev_b[dev], dev_c[dev], Ns[dev] );
    }
}
```

In above code he added `NS[dev]` also to add function but, man who sends the question posts add function like this:

```
__global__ void add( double *a, double *b, double *c){

    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 

    while(tid < N){
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }

}
```

What is the function of  `Ns[dev]` in above function. Because when i remove  `Ns[dev]` in below code, like this:

```
add<<<NB,NT>>>( dev_a[dev], dev_b[dev], dev_c[dev]);
```

Add function does not work. I mean it does not adds the values.

How can i use  `Ns[dev]` in add function here?

Answer (score 1):

In the linked answer, `Ns` is an array specifying the amount of data which should be processed by each device. `dev` is the id of the current device.

You should add an argument to the kernel which should specify the length of the data being processed in the kernel.

```
__global__ void add( double *a, double *b, double *c, const int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 

    while(tid < N){
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}
```