# cuGraph on Multi-GPU

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu, rapids

Recently, I am reading the code of cuGraph. I notice that it is mentioned that Louvain and Katz algorithms support multi-GPU. However, when I read the C++ code of [Louvain](https://github.com/rapidsai/cugraph/blob/branch-21.06/cpp/src/community/louvain.cu), I cannot find code that is related to multi-GPU. Specifically, according to a prior [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529972/multi-gpu-basic-usage), multi-GPU can be implemented by calling `cudaSetDevice`. I cannot find this function in the code of Louvain, however. Am I missing anything?

Comment: cuGraph is current working on a better multi-GPU C++ API.  that should be out on a few months (22.02 or 22.04 release).  Until then, take a look at the multi-GPU test for connected components, you can easily just change the name of the function called to be Louvain.  
https://github.com/rapidsai/cugraph/blob/branch-21.12/cpp/tests/components/mg_weakly_connected_components_test.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cuGraph supports multi-GPU by leveraging Dask. I encourage you to read the Dask cuGraph [documentation](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cugraph/nightly/dask-cugraph.html) that shows an example using PageRank.

For a Louvain example, I recommend looking at the docstring of the `cugraph.dask.louvain` function.

For completeness, under the hood cuGraph is using [RAFT](https://github.com/rapidsai/raft) to manage underlying NCCL and UCX communication.

Comment: It seems that Dask is in Python. But the code in the link I provided is in C++.

Comment: Since you're already looking at the cuGraph codebase, I encourage you to look at the dask components in the python namespace. You will see that Dask ultimately delegates the communication to RAFT, which handles it.